# Regex: Exclude everything but number, space, plus sign and period

Tags: javascript, regex

I´m trying to test if a string has ANY character different than: `number (0 to 9), space ( ), period (.) or negative sign (-)`

My best shoot after hours is: `([\d\s]|[.-])`
Which does the opposite, it selects numbers, spaces, periods and minus.

The idea, then, is to use `.test()` to check if it has letters, other characters or symbols, etc like: `pattern.test(string)`

I tried to use the negative `?!` but I still cannot make it work.

What am I doing bad? I´m new with regex and I´m trying to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a negative character set, and put the permitted characters into the set, thus matching anything that's not in the set:

```js
const re = /[^0-9 .-]/;
const test = str => {
  if (re.test(str)) {
    console.log('Other characters are included');
  } else {
    console.log('All characters in string are permitted');
  }
};
test('1234');
test('foo3');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried hours and I could not see it. I´m seeing it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead:

`(?!...)` - Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters.

So, your final expression might look like this: `(?![\d\s]|[.-]).`

But of course, the previous answer is more simple: `[^0-9 .-]`

I find this tool very useful for regex: https://regex101.com
It helps to test and it contains some examples and explanation.

Screenshot: https://monosnap.com/image/YVBDVzEV8yT8Gic0av74nhW3jIWwyR.png